# Concerns about flagging an answer before it was deleted

Tags: discussion, flags

I just saw an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54454588/9134576) which is not an answer for sure.

So, I did what I should, i.e., flagged as "Not an answer", informed answerer that it is not an answer and down-voted that right away.

Then, answerer deleted the answer, now my flag was marked as helpful.

But, then answerer undeleted the answer again as you can see in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54454588/timeline).

So, I was wondering if moderators will still look on to that, or I've to flag that again. Because for a long time the question is not deleted by moderators.

And if I should flag that again, then which flag should I raise? As "Not an answer" has been greyed out, stating *You have already raised this type of flag*.

Here is the question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54454531/) and answer snapshot, just in case the answer get deleted, for future users:

[image: Answer snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer has entered the review queue for [a second time](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22078596). I'm not sure, but I have the feeling that the user can repeatedly undelete the answer following deletion in review if they're *that* keen to have it as an answer.

Failing that they could just repost the same answer to the question again.

The bottom line is that:

- Your original flag hasn't been declined (and was marked helpful rather than disputed).
- The answer will likely be deleted once more.

Personally I would suggest you move on and not worry about it - unless that user repeatedly does this, in which case a moderator could possibly get involved, but they're likely busy enough as they are with other moderation to deal with specific cases like this unless it's a pattern by the user.

Comment: Yes, I know that my flag is marked helpful. But I think SO should change the status of flag if post was undeleted.

Comment: What would you want to happen? In principle the user could undelete and fix their answer, making it a 'proper' answer. That's probably why they have the ability to undelete in the first instance.

Comment: Yes you are right, but if a post was undeleted, then atleast I should have the ability to flag it again with the same flag.

Comment: I suspect that this is by design to prevent [edit war](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/)-style flag/delete cycles.